# twilio Record entire incoming call with gather

Tags: django, twilio, voice-recording, twilio-twiml

I am conducting a survey using Voice with Twilio. Part of that survey is to let the user give a voice feedback so i used Record at first. That was exactly what i needed since i could get the mp3 + the transcription. Problem is : i can't set the language to French so my transcription come in french, instead it is recorded and transcribed as english even though i speak french.

So i decided to switch and use the Gather with the speech option which works quite well, the text comes back in french, but using that option, i can't get the mp3.

So i decided that i would record the entire call, and use Gather which would have solved my problem, except you only get to set the record parameter to true when you initiate the call (outgoing call). My survey will be taken by incoming call 95% of the time..

I there any way to achieve this without having to use Record and use another API to do the transcription ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid, in the situation you are in, where you need the mp3s and French transcription, then I can only recommend using [`<Record>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record) and a third party transcription service. [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) with input type speech just doesn't support this kind of recording yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you have a third party transcription service to recommand ?

Comment: If you were having good results with the Twilio speech detection in `<Gather>` that is powered by [Google's cloud speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/) so you might try that.